# How can I get form data into a model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a model called `Note`:

```
class Note(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()


    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
        from notes.tasks import build_htaccess
        super(Note, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
        build_htaccess.delay(self.id) # celery tasks
```

I have a modelform like so:

```
from django import forms

from notes.models import Note


class AddNoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)


    class Meta:
        model = Note
```

I do not want to store the `password` value in the database because I am overriding the save method to create an htaccess password via `subprocess` but I can't seem to access the form cleaned_data to get the password value in my model into the save override. Any suggestions as to how I can do this?

Comment: you will have to pass the password as a parameter to your save function in a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question this raises for me is, if you're not storing the field value in the database why include it in a model at all?

I can't picture your precise endgame here, but what I would probably do in a situation similar to the one you're describing is create the password field by hand in the template. Then, I could grab the value of the field from the `request.POST` data within my view using something along the lines of the following:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    [...]
    if myPassHandler(request.POST['password']):
        # password is valid
        [...]
    else:
        # bad password
        [...]
```

Where `myPassHandler` returns True or False. Hope this helps some.